# Files corupted durring copy

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, hard-drive, file-corruption

While copying/downloading a large file (3+ GB) the checksusms aren't the same afterwards.

Methods attempted:

- A patch cable transfer between two computers. (source sum was OK)
- Download from Main site.
- Copy from another partition. (the original sum was OK)

The file is an ISO for a Debian-Based OS. (but this is not the only file that has had problems...)

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Mac OSX El Capitian, and have had this problem on both. However with the Mac I was eventually able to get the file correctly.

I have run the `badblocks` command (on entire disk) and `fsck.ext4` (Only on the Ububntu partition) from a live CD and no problems were reported. More over the SMARTS report for the drive reports the disk is OK.

**Could this be a drive failure, and is there anything else I can do to check the integrity of the Hard Drive?**

## UPDATE:

So another intersting thing is going on... I ran the sha1sum once and got:
`87004a6bea1ff1792f733f9048b3c43b7a2c66af` I just ran it three more times and got `6607f5a66aee980a8958bb99f9871158a852a319` `91b8a6674b9a90ab07c151cedc203a2d9806193f` and
`076d303bbbce719edffd9ed821bc83c448d42bb4`. I have made no changes to this file... Any ideas?

## UPDATE 2:

I just restarted my system and the sum has stopped "shifting"... So it appears I might have cut it off mid write, even though `cp` returned... I am confused at this point as to why it is hanging out in a buffer for so long. Anyone know what I can do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing bad RAM - it can cause small errors when files are copied, and can be very intermittent, if it's only a small spot of ram that's not always used. I'd expect to see mention of disk read errors in `dmesg` or /var/log/syslog.

Check with `memtest` for a few passes, when the computer's "warmed up." I've read that running it for 24hrs is a 100% reliable test, but just a few minutes would find any big errors, an hour should be good.

---

If the files fit in RAM, they could be only read from disk once, and subsequent reads are from the disk cache in RAM. To clear/flush the disk cache and try another read from disk, run:

```
sync; echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Echoing 3 clears all caches, echoing 1 only clears the pagecache (disk caches & other caches *I think*), 2 frees reclaimable slab objects (includes dentries and inodes) - See [Kernel Documentation for /proc/sys/vm/*](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. It was one of the sticks of RAM.